# Angular 2: From content of <router-outlet>, link to a route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 component which has routing config:

```
{ path: '/all', component:app.ListsHomeComponent, name:'Home', useAsDefault:true }
```

I want to have links on my ListsHomeComponent that link to routes, like this:

```
'<a [routerLink]="[\'Home\']">Home</a>'
```

But of course, ListsHomeComponent doesn't have a RouterConfig, and I get an error to that effect. And if I copy the router config in from the other component, it tries to do nested routing and throws a different error. How should I go about doing this?

[edit] A plunk with the problem I describe. Notice the Javascript errors you get: http://plnkr.co/edit/Up6YZvkQ1OocDOvDJLBo?p=preview

Comment: Please post a plunk to get better answers faster

Comment: Good point, I've added a link to a (non) working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Up6YZvkQ1OocDOvDJLBo?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix the route name with a slash an absolute route is used AFAIK

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
```